# I need to find the prime index but my while loop is exiting?

Tags: javascript, binary-search

```js
var doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    var min = 0;
    var max = array.length - 1;
    var guess = Math.floor((min + max) / 2);
    var values = array[guess];

    while (min < max) {
        if (values < targetValue) {
            min = guess + 1;
        } else if (values > targetValue) {
            max = guess - 1;
        }

        return guess
    }

    return -1;
};

var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

var result = doSearch(primes, 73);

alert("Found prime at index " + result);
```

Comment: Please fix code formatting and add it to jsfiddle.net so we can debug it much easier.

Comment: Because you evaluate the halfway point once, and then **immediately** `return guess` -- it will always return that halfway point, plus or minus 1. Move that line out of the `while`. (And fix more -- this is not *the* answer!)

Comment: @Jongware yes u r ryt i wrote "return guess" out of the while loop and also  var guess = Math.floor((min + max) / 2);
    var values = array[guess];  pasted the code in the while loop but now i get the index 19 not 20

Comment: @Niko check my code, you should get 20

Comment: @Amir its working here but not in the Khan academy editor , it still saying Found prime at index -1 .

Comment: @Niko can you post link

Comment: @Amir https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/p/challenge-binary-search

Comment: @Amir it Worked i forgot to change min < max to min <= max thankx a alot :D

Comment: @Niko no prob, please mark this question as solved if you don't have more questions

Comment: @Amir the answer is right but still not going forward to next level https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/p/challenge-binary-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't update guess value after `min` or `max` moved.
2. Your loop returns the first guess, which should be done only if guessed value equals to searched value.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ybtjw1x9/)**

There is multiple things that you need to fix in the code, check my comments:

```js
var doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    var min = 0;
    var max = array.length - 1;
    var guess;
    var values;

    while (min <= max) { // "less or equal" otherwise some case won't work
        guess = Math.floor((min + max) / 2); // guess needs to be assigned every loop
        values = array[guess]; // values need to be updated in every loop
        
        if (values < targetValue) {
            min = guess + 1;
        } else if (values > targetValue) {
            max = guess - 1;
        } else{
            return guess // This is only when values == targetValue, if no else was used, it will return from the first loop
        }
    }

    return -1;
};

var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

var result = doSearch(primes, 73);

alert("Found prime at index " + result);
```